# Adjust height of div to be based on content within div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm absolutely terrible at CSS and I'm wondering how I can set the height of the div to be the height of the content within.

I've tried a variety of ways based on what other Stack Overflow questions are suggesting with no luck so it must be down to the way I'm structuring the HTML in the React application.

The structure of the HTML looks like so

```html
<div className="OrderDetails">
      <div className="OrderDetails__main">
        {
          isFetching
            ? (<Loader message="Fetching Order Details" />)
            : (
              <>
                <div className="OrderDetails__main--header">
                  <h5 className="pt-2">{`Details For Order: ${orderDetails.purchaseOrderNumber}`}</h5>
                  <h5 className="pt-2">{`Order Placed: ${moment(orderDetails.orderPlacedAt).format(DateFormats.dayMonthYearHourMinuteV2)}`}</h5>
                  <h5 className="pt-2">{`Order Status: ${orderDetails.orderStatus}`}</h5>
                </div>
                <div className="OrderDetails__main--details">
                  <div className="OrderDetails__main--section py-3">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div className="OrderDetails__main--section px-2 py-3">
                    
                  </div>
                  <div className="OrderDetails__main--section py-3">
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the supporting SCSS looks like so

```css
.OrderDetails {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  &__main {
    width: 95vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;

    &--header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 5vh;
      width: 90vw;
      margin: .5rem auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
    }

    &--details {
      display: flex;
      width: 90vw;
      margin: .5rem auto;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &--section {
      width: 28vw;
      height: inherit;
    }
  }
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out I was applying

height: fit-content;

to the --details div when it should have been added to the __main class